# How does Apple's site enable sliding the images on its slider with the finger?

Tags: iphone, css

I meant sliding the images in the slider with my finger. I can slide them left and right, pause etc. by using my finger.

This is the page: http://www.apple.com/tw/iphone/

Apparently you can slide the images with your finger. I tried this on my Android phone but it didn't work thought. I think it only works on iPhone.

How did they archive that?

Comment: with the use of swipe gesture you can achieve the slider images.

Comment: @eptdeveloper Is that something proper of the iPhone? jQuery?

Comment: iphone has default properties of swipe and that can be added over UIView and other objects as well but have no idea about jQuery sorry.